# Apollo Graphql - Send query to multiple hosts serving same schema but subset of data

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have 2 graphql services, each serving a subset of data with the same schema.

```
Service1 has a list of Users with ID 1-10,000
Service2 has a list of Users with ID 10,001-20,000
```

My User Type looks like

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

Each service has a graphql query to resolve a user.

```
type Query {
  fetchUser(id: ID!): User
  fetchUsers: [User!]
}
```

Is there a way that apollo can query both services and merge the results,
So I dont have to query each service individually?

Comment: I need this capability as well.  Have you found an answer?  I recently posted the same question for the C# HotChocolate library:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560283/hotchocolate-merge-two-services-that-have-the-same-schema